# Notice: Array to string conversion PHP

Tags: php, mysql

This code says

```
Notice: Array to string conversion
```

But I don't see the problem I have done some Google searches but there is to many function to apply can you tell what is the exact problem and what solution to apply?

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT  content_copy_f.img3,content_copy_f.img2,content_copy_f.idParent,content_copy_f.idContent,
                             count(content_copy_f.idParent) as Co,
                             content_copy_f.texte,content_copy_f.img1,content_copy_f.legende1 FROM
                             content_copy_f,content_copy_p WHERE content_copy_f.idParent=content_copy_p.idContent
                             group by content_copy_f.idParent")or die(mysqli_error($con));

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 //j'ai défini la varialbe image pour que php ne dit pas que la variable image n'est pas définie
 $image=" ";
 //test select les images avant update la table content_copy_p (verifier si le champ image est vide)
 //daba dirha sql query 
 $p=0;
 for($i=1;$i<=$row['Co'];$i++){
     $image =$row['img'.$i];
 $result2=mysqli_query($con,"update content_copy_p set img'".[$i]."'='".$image."'");
 $p++;
 if($p==3){$i=$row['Co'];}
}
//$image=$image.",".$row['idParent']."<br>";
        // echo $image;//*/
//fin test

}
```

Comment: ...`"update content_copy_p set img'".[$i]`...

Comment: i dont get it what do you mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[]` "tags" are shortcode for arrays.

Change your query to;

```
$result2=mysqli_query($con,"update content_copy_p set img".$i."='".$image."'");
```

- Removed `[]` tags around `$i`
- Unquoted `$i` as it looks like you want it concatenated to `img`